# Is there a limit to the arrays I can use with WordPress meta_query?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to make a custom search form where each post has custom meta data. When I filter by two key values I can get the results I search for. But when I add a third array, amenities, the results don't appear.

I'm wondering if I can only pass two arrays within the meta_data argument. I don't know just guessing.

Here is my query argument:

```html
 $args_listings = array( 
  'cat' => 'listings',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'key'     => 'neighborhood',
     'value'   => $neighborhoodlist,
     ),
    array(
     'key'     => 'bedrooms',
     'value'   => $bedroomnum,
     ),
    array(
     'key'     => 'amenities',
     'value'   => $amenitieslist,
     ),
  ),

 );
```